# Pydantic Not Deserializing Sqlalchemy when I query using with entities

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

I use this part of code to get data from the db

```
class OrmModel(BaseModel):
    class Config:
        orm_mode = True

class PruebaVozFila(OrmModel):
    id:int 
    id_origen:int 
    id_destino:int
    hora_programada:str
    hora_ejecutada:str 
    exitoso:bool 
    estado:str 
@router.get("/pruebas-voz",response_model=PruebaVozFila)
def obtener_pruebas_voz(
    *,
    db: Session = Depends(deps.get_db),
    current_user: models.User = Depends(deps.get_current_active_user),
    search:Search = Depends(Search)
    ) -> Any:

    temporal_query = db.query(PruebaVoz).filter().with_entities(
        
    PruebaVoz.id,
    PruebaVoz.id_origen,
    PruebaVoz.id_destino,
    PruebaVoz.hora_programada,
    PruebaVoz.hora_ejecutada,
    PruebaVoz.exitoso,
    PruebaVoz.estado,

    ).first()

    return  jsonable_encoder(temporal_query)
```

So when I query without using 'with_entities' it works but if I add it,it throws the following error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4NyG.png)

It seems that Pydantic is unable to find the columns or its names inside  the temporal_query
I print the query as SQL and gives me this
With "with_entities"

```
SELECT pruebavoz.id AS pruebavoz_id, pruebavoz.id_origen AS pruebavoz_id_origen, pruebavoz.id_destino AS pruebavoz_id_destino, pruebavoz.hora_programada AS pruebavoz_hora_programada, pruebavoz.hora_ejecutada AS pruebavoz_hora_ejecutada, pruebavoz.exitoso AS pruebavoz_exitoso, pruebavoz.estado AS pruebavoz_estado
```

Without "with_entities"

```
SELECT pruebavoz.id AS pruebavoz_id, pruebavoz.id_origen AS pruebavoz_id_origen, pruebavoz.id_destino AS pruebavoz_id_destino, pruebavoz.hora_programada AS pruebavoz_hora_programada, pruebavoz.hora_ejecutada AS pruebavoz_hora_ejecutada, pruebavoz.exitoso AS pruebavoz_exitoso, pruebavoz.estado AS pruebavoz_estado, pruebavoz.usuario_ingreso AS pruebavoz_usuario_ingreso, pruebavoz.creado AS pruebavoz_creado, pruebavoz.actualizado AS pruebavoz_actualizado
```

as you see  in the actual query the parameters are the same.What do you think is happening.

Comment: Try this `response_model=List[PruebaVozFila]`

Comment: Tried response_model=List[PruebaVozFila]  but the following error is showed
backend_1       | response -> 0 -> id
backend_1       |   field required (type=value_error.missing)
I think Pydantic is not getting the right value from the result set. Even if I use
    class Config:
        orm_mode = True

Comment: Why you are not using Config inside `PruebaVozFila` class?

Comment: class OrmModel(BaseModel):
    class Config:
        orm_mode = True

class PruebaVozFila(OrmModel):
    id:int 
    id_origen:int 
    id_destino:int
    hora_programada:str
    hora_ejecutada:str 
    exitoso:bool 
    estado:str
The orm model is used as a parent class to the PruebaVozFila so inherits the config class

Comment: I mean you can add class Config inside Your PruebaVozFila

Comment: jsonable_encoderBut i think your problem comes from your returning value change  return statement with pass and tell me the output

Comment: fixed it  using 
self.data =  jsonable_encoder( [ row_class.from_orm(row) for row in all_items] )
it seems that from_orm uses the class variables as a dict so it can deserialize now

Comment: Perfect, glad you find a way, please write it as an answer.